# Get Mobile Phone OS over Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, mobile-phones

Is it possible to check over Bluetooth if Android is running on a mobile phone?

Comment: Are we talking a paired&bonded device, or a random device which you may have never connected to before?

Comment: Another question is, how are you getting the Bluetooth MAC of the remote device? Android devices are not discoverable except for brief periods when the user puts it into discover mode. So if you put the device into discover mode to get the MAC then you already know whether its an Android device.

Comment: yes then i know that my device is a android device, but i don't know which of the devices i found during discoverable time are android devices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's a random/untrusted device you'll have to rely on passive techniques and statistical analysis:

- Does the Bluetooth MAC fall into a range known to be used by certain Android hardware
- Fingerprint the SDP records returned by the device. For example, my A855 returns a whole bunch of SDP records which could be used to distinguish it from other types of devices. (Linux command `$ sdptool  browse <Bluetooth MAC>`)
- Is the device discoverable? (Does it show up in a scan for nearby devices?) Because Android defaults to not discoverable.

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth spec does not send any SO specific information. You should send that info programatically, and after the connection has been stablished, of course.

Comment: hmm ok then there is no way to detect that before connection establishment?